# Formulario por POST no envía dato correctamente

Tags: php

Tengo un problema al enviar un dato por `POST`.

El el siguiente código se asigna una materia a un alumno, la funcion `comprobarDni` comprueba si el alumno existe, si es cierto se ejecuta la funcion `form2()` para asignar una materia a un alumno.

El problema lo tengo en la siguiente línea :

```
$secretaria->asignarMateria(isset($_POST['test']),$_POST['buscaDni']);
```

Si por ejemplo lo pongo manualmente funciona correctamente :

```
$secretaria->asignarMateria("Matemáticas", $_POST['buscaDni']);
```

El problema creo que lo tengo en `isset($_POST['test'])` ya que parece que no recibe el texto que le paso por formulario.

Os dejo parte del código, no lo pongo completo ya que hay muchas líneas que creo que son innecesarias para resolver este problema :

```
   include_once("alumno.php");
   include_once("materia.php");

    class Secretaria{

        public $alumnos = array();
        public $materias = array();

        public function asignarMateria($pName, $dName) {

            $materia = $this->buscarMateria($pName);
            $alumno = $this->buscarAlumno($dName);
            if($materia && $alumno) {

                $alumno->materiasAsignadas[] = $materia;
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public function comprobarDni($nombre) {

            if(array_search($nombre, array_column($this->alumnos, 'nombre')) !== false) {

                return true;
            }
            else {
                formularioAltaAlumno();
            }
        }
    }

    $secretaria = new Secretaria();


    function form(){
        echo '<FORM METHOD="POST" >
        <label>Introduce el dni del alumno : </label><INPUT class="form" TYPE = "text" NAME = "buscaDni"> <br>
        <INPUT class="form" TYPE = "submit" VALUE = "Busca" name="action">
        </ FORM>';
    }

    function form2(){

        echo '<FORM METHOD="POST" >
        <label>Add the subject : </label><INPUT TYPE = "text" NAME = "test"> <br>
        <INPUT class="form" TYPE = "submit" name="action">
        </ FORM>';
    }

    if(isset($_POST['action']))
    {
        switch($_POST['action'])
        {

            case 'Busca':

                if($secretaria->comprobarDni($_POST['buscaDni']) == true){

                    form2();

                    $secretaria->asignarMateria(isset($_POST['test']), $_POST['buscaDni']);
                }
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: por que lo tienes en dos formularios diferentes?

Comment: El formulario form() envía el DNI, comprueba si este existe o no, si existe se ejecuta el form2() para asignar la materia a un alumno, el código es más extenso pero no lo he puesto completo para poder comprender mejor el problema.

Comment: intenta imprimir con echo que es lo que llega a $_POST['test'] al principio, si es q llega vacio entonces hay q revisar de donde se esta enviando

Comment: He puesto echo $_POST['test'] al principio del codigo y si que me muestra lo que escribo por formulario, pero no sé por que no me lo guarda aquí :  $secretaria->asignarMateria(isset($_POST['test']),$_POST['buscaDni']);

Answer (score 1):

EL metodo `isset` te devuelve true si esta definida la variable:

```
if(isset($_POST['test'])){

    $secretaria->asignarMateria($_POST['test'],$_POST['buscaDni']);
}
```